# Why is my Intel RAID controller incompatible with Linux dmraid in USB-booted Linux recovery environment?

Tags: usb, raid, bootable

I have a Windows 10 system running a pair of disks in a mirrored RAID 1 configuration.

I am trying to understand why the Linux-based FixMeStick product does not work with my RAID drives and hangs. This product runs virus scanners on locally installed hard drives in a USB-booted Linux environment.

I'm trying to figure out a way the dmraid tool could be used to access my 1+1 RAID set, I have not tried this manually yet with a custom Ubuntu bootable environment.

The FixMeStick owner tells me that his Linux based bootable USB product uses the dmraid package to work with RAID drives, and he is wondering if it is compatible with my RAID controller:

- I have an ASUS Z490-A motherboard. The server was built in May, 2021.
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700K CPU @ 3.80GHz 3.79 GHz
- The Intel Driver and Support Assistant reports the following:

  ```
  Intel Raid 1 Volume Driver Details Provider
  Microsoft Version10.0.19041.1865 
  Date6/21/2006 
  Firmware Details Version1.0. 
  Device Details Capacity 5589.02 GB 
  Serial Number Volume1 
  Partitions 2 
  Device Id SCSI\DISK&VEN_INTEL&PROD_RAID_1_VOLUME\4&31E325C3&0&060000 
  Device Path \.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 E: 
  File System NTFS 
  Compressed False 
  Capacity 1844.37 GB 
  Free Space 1603.49 GB F: 
  File System NTFS 
  Compressed False 
  Capacity 3744.64 GB
  ```
- In Device Manager, I see

  ```
  Storage controllers / Intel Chipset SATA RAID Controller
  with driver date 2/8/2018, version 15.44.0.1015.
  ```

It does not appear I am using either Optane or RST RAID controllers, but I don't really know what specific kind of RAID controller I have, nor how to obtain documentation.

I'm also not sure if my RAID controller is hardware, firmware or software based.

Can anybody help clarify / educate ?

I've also posted in the [Intel forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Rapid-Storage-Technology/Why-is-my-Intel-RAID-controller-incompatible-with-Linux-dmraid/m-p/1404066/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEw2NElKNUY4Tkg2NllHfDE0MDQwNjZ8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M11162)

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing like RAID 1+1

Comment: I'm seriously thinking of adding a hardware RAID controller and circumventing all this madness.

Comment: Try to boot conventional Linux Live CD (e.g. Ubuntu or something like that). See if it "hangs". Look how it sees your disks and what's on them (usually `lsblk` and `blkid` are sufficient). In principle, if your controller uses `imsm` (older Intel) or `ddf` (quite typical) on-disk metadata, Linux should support that out of the box with *MD* driver (not DMRAID), so it'll show as `/dev/mdX` and should be listed in `/proc/mdstat`. Windows "LDM" software RAID could be supported with `ldmtool` (see .e.g [here](https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-properly-access-windows-software-raid-0/)).

Answer (score 0):

What problem you try to solve?
Check windows disks configuration. If you have 2 disks in Disk Managment it is software raid.
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-mirror-boot-hard-drive-on-windows-10-legacy-or-uefi

Try boot from SustemRescueCD.
https://www.system-rescue.org/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239082/reassemble-intel-rst-raid-on-another-mainboard

Also read manual and check bios configutation https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-Z490-A/HelpDesk_Manual/